# Facebook post to group oAuth Access Token Issue

Tags: c#, facebook

I know this question gets asked a lot but I cant seem to make this work. I am prying to post to my Facebook Group. I keep getting a (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action error. I am using .NET 4.5 and the Facebook SDK 6.4.2. Thanks.

```
dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
            messagePost.picture = "http://www.yaplex.com/logos/yaplex-logo-with-text-small.png";
            messagePost.link = "http://yaplex.com/";
            messagePost.name = "[name] Facebook name...";
            messagePost.caption = " Facebook caption";
            messagePost.description = "[description] Facebook description...";
            messagePost.message = "[message] Facebook message...";

            const string acccessToken = "xxxx";
            var appp = new FacebookClient(acccessToken);
            try
            {
                appp.Post("xxxxx" + "/feed", messagePost);
            }
            catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
            {
                //handle oauth exception
            }
            catch (FacebookApiException ex)
            {
                //handle facebook exception
            }
```

Comment: Where's your login code? Are you requesting the correct permission from the user?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to publish to a User's feed, you need to make sure that you gathered the "publish_actions" permission for the respective Access Token.

See docs here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/#publish